# Whats the point of Tuple(Of T)

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, .net-4.0, tuples

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the purpose of the Tuple(T1)/Singleton in .net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121025/whats-the-purpose-of-the-tuplet1-singleton-in-net)

Trying to mimic a Tuple as implemented in .Net 4 (For .Net 3) I just realized there is a Tuple(Of T)? This was quite a surprize!

Why would anyone do this

```
Tuple<string> result = new Tuple<string>("Data");
```

Instead of this

```
return "Data";
```

Isn't the whole point of a tuple that its a container for "loosely related data that isnt cohesive enough to make another class"? Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry about that, I did look, just missed that one.

Answer (score 3):

There are a finite number of tuple-arities in the library, so to define an 8-tuple, you use the kind with 7-elements whose 'rest' argument is a one-tuple.  See

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383325.aspx

Comment: This does not answer the question at all.  The OP is asking, "Why have a Tuple of only one item?"  That seems a reasonable question to ask.

Comment: How is this an answer to the question?

Comment: Why the hatred for this answer?  The linked MSDN page gives an explicit example of when a single-element tuple is *required*, such as when providing the TRest parameter for an 8-tuple.

Comment: It might be from MSDN, but it doesn't answer OP's original question.

Answer (score 1):

This is a carry over from set theory that might not have much use for a software developer.

Tuples are simply ordered lists of elements.  An N-tuple has n elements, and n can be one, which is called a singleton.  You probably won't have much use for a 1-tuple in code, but I'm guessing the C# team put it in there for completeness.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple#Etymology

Comment: So we all agree that a Tuple of one item is inherently useless?

Comment: For software development, I can't think of a use for it.  Maybe if you were writing a program to model a mathematical set???  You should email Eric Lippert a link to this question, maybe he'll provide some input tomorrow

Comment: So you are, I guess, hypothesizing on the utility of a stock BCL class in a realm other than software development?

Comment: @Kirk, no, I'm saying that a 1-tuple does exist in math.  I'm surmising that the C# team included it for consistency, even though you likely won't use it often.