# What uses are there for a Tuple with one generic type parameter?

Tags: c#, generics, tuples

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the purpose of the Tuple(T1)/Singleton in .net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121025/whats-the-purpose-of-the-tuplet1-singleton-in-net)

Is the only reason `Tuple<T1>` exists for constancy with the other tuples with more generic type parameters? Maybe it makes reflection code not have to deal with the special case of a single type?

Does it have any use on its own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are quite right - it avoids the special case. If you are writing a code generator, you don't have to special case for a single type parameter, for example.

From the documentation - [Tuple(Of T1) Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd386941.aspx):

> A singleton is used comparatively rarely in application development.