# Why use a 1-tuple, Tuple<T1> in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, tuples

I don't see the use of 1-tuples in C#. Why do programmers use them?

[Tuple Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd386941%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

I have seen a declaration like the following:

`Tuple<string> state;`

But I wonder if there are further uses.

Comment: because we can use `Tuple<Tuple<T1,T2,..>>`?

Comment: I personally stay away from Tuples since they're rather vague to me and feel a little lazy (maybe I am missing something). Creating a class to store say a row of data is far more explicit in my opinion.

Comment: Was preparing a short code sample of when a Tuple *could* hypothetically be used, but since the question is marked as duplicate, posted it in the old thread: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31135334/1431042

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Tuple classes only go up to 7. When you need an 8-tuple, you have to use

```
Tuple<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, Tuple<T8>>
```

But if you need 8 items, you probably want to redesign your application.

You can go as far as you want, as long as you chain tuples together. 15 items:

```
Tuple<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7,
    Tuple<T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, Tuple<T15>>>
```

Note that C# will throw a runtime exception if the last item (TRest) is not a tuple (since it cannot be enforced at compile-time because the ITuple interface is `internal`)

Comment: @xanatos You will get a runtime exception, because int does not implement ITuple.

Comment: And then you will do t.Rest.Item1? This is not uniform.

Comment: @Dennis_E Fascinating... You should write it in the response. Considering they had the `internal interface ITuple` that they used on all the `Tuple`, it is strange they didn't use it.

Comment: This is not true, why would it get a runtime exception? https://ideone.com/zWjl4P There is no `where` clause at the Tumple<8> definition for TRest.

Comment: @Andrey `Tuple.Create` will create a `Tuple<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, Tuple<T8>` Try `new Tuple<int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int>(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)`

Comment: @Andrey If there were a `where` clause, it'd be a compile-time error. There [is indeed a runtime check in the source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/tuple.cs,7faa1809fba73e9f).

Comment: @Andrey https://ideone.com/UIiljk

Comment: @xanatos ok, this is weird, why does Create allow it but constructor does not.

Comment: @Andrey Watch what the `Create` will create for you: `Tuple<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, Tuple<T8>>`. You can't even use it for creating `Tuple<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, Tuple<T8, T9>>`! Its signature is borderline nonsensical.

Comment: The 8-tuple is a special case. If you need more items, you need to use the (ugly) constructor explicitly. But you can easily write a factory method for that as well: ideone.com/UDHx3E